# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un evento se ejecute cuando un form se cierra? C#

Tags: c#

Hola soy nuevo en programación, y quería saber como puedo hacer para que Form 1 ejecute un evento, cuando Form 2 se cierra. Estuve buscando un tiempo y encontré el evento Form.Closing, pero se ejecutaría en el Form 2. Desde ya, Gracias.

Comment: y... todo depende como form1 haya llamado a form2... o si form2 conoce a form1... o todas esas cosas.. nos muestras esos detalles de tu codigo?

Comment: Perdón, pero no entiendo tu pregunta, ¿me podrías explicar?

Comment: Nos mostras como es tu codigo? como se comunican form1 y form2?

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.nombre = textBox1.Text;`